# Doctrine annotation exception when using parse query in Symfony2

Tags: rest, symfony, doctrine-orm, parse-platform, symfony-2.5

I'm trying to make an API Rest in Symfony2 using Parse as cloud database.

If I try to retrieve the Parse users it works fine and returns the expected data.

Local url example: http://www.foo.local/app_dev.php/getUsers/

Here is the code I use in the Users controller (I use annotations in order to set the routes in the controller):

```
namespace Foo\ApiBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseUser;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * @return array
    * @View()
    * @Route("/getUsers/")
    */
    public function getUsersAction(Request $request) {
        ParseClient::initialize(<my Parse keys>);

        $query = ParseUser::query();     
        $results = $query->find();

        return array('users' => $results);
    } 
}
```

However if I try the same with my Products ParseObjects, I get the following error message:

> error code="500" message="Internal Server Error" exception
>   class="Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException"
>   message="[Semantical Error] The annotation "@returns" in method
>   Parse\ParseFile::getData() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to
>   add a "use" statement for this annotation?"

Local url example: http://www.foo.local/app_dev.php/getProducts/

The Products controller code:

```
namespace Foo\ApiBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseFile;

class ProductsController extends Controller 
{
    /**
     * @return array
     * @View()
     * @Route("/getProducts/")
     */
    public function getProductsAction(Request $request) {
        ParseClient::initialize(<my Parse keys>);

        $query = new ParseQuery("Products");
        $results = $query->find();

        return array('products' => $results);    
    }
}
```

If instead of returning `$results` I return other dummy data, like `return array('products' => 'fooProducts')`, I no longer get the error message.

Also if I make a `var_dump` of the `$results` variable, I get the expected array of ParseObjects.

Here is my routing.yml file in case there is something wrong with it:

```
api:
    resource: "@FooApiBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

users:
    type: rest
    resource: Foo\ApiBundle\Controller\UsersController

products:
    type: rest
    resource: Foo\ApiBundle\Controller\ProductsController
```

By the error message it seems that the problem is related to Doctrine, but since I'm not using it, I don't know exactly how there can be a conflict or how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems they are using the wrong DocBlock `@returns` should be `@return` as far as I know. It seems to bounce between the two throughout the class.

Comment: Agreed with @Qoop, and I have no idea to work around that.. maybe try and put the `use` statements for `Parse` above the rest of the annotation classes? I'm going to make a pull request to fix the DocBlocks

Comment: Try [using this fork](https://github.com/sjagr/parse-php-sdk) and see if it fixes your problem. I've made a pull request to the original devs

Comment: Indeed your solution worked, thanks! May be you could create an answer with this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few DocBlock typos of `@returns` in the `Parse\ParseFile` class that is causing Doctrine's Annotations class to attempt to identify them as a class. This is not your fault but a bug in the Parse PHP SDK library.

I've [made a fix in this commit](https://github.com/sjagr/parse-php-sdk/commit/5f5579e061105e2a89d551ce4bf223ecfb87aabb) and submitted a pull request back to the original devs, so it should be a simple matter of eventually running `composer update` to bring your Parse library to the latest correct version.

[You can read more about DocBlock and the part specifically on Annotations here](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/docblocks.html#annotations)

Here is a copy/paste of the resulting diff for `src/Parse/ParseFile.php`:

```
@@ -31,7 +31,7 @@ class ParseFile implements \Parse\Internal\Encodable
   /**
    * Return the data for the file, downloading it if not already present.
    *
-   * @returns mixed
+   * @return mixed
    *
    * @throws ParseException
    */
 @@ -50,7 +50,7 @@ public function getData()
   /**
    * Return the URL for the file, if saved.
    *
-   * @returns string|null
+   * @return string|null
    */
   public function getURL()
   {
 @@ -112,7 +112,7 @@ public function getMimeType()
    * @param string $name The file name on Parse, can be used to detect mimeType
    * @param string $mimeType Optional, The mime-type to use when saving the file
    *
-   * @returns ParseFile
+   * @return ParseFile
    */
   public static function createFromData($contents, $name, $mimeType = null)
   {
 @@ -132,7 +132,7 @@ public static function createFromData($contents, $name, $mimeType = null)
    * @param string $name Filename to use on Parse, can be used to detect mimeType
    * @param string $mimeType Optional, The mime-type to use when saving the file
    *
-   * @returns ParseFile
+   * @return ParseFile
    */
   public static function createFromFile($path, $name, $mimeType = null)
   {
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to initialize Parse using Symfony, is on the setContainer method of your controller:

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    ....

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        parent::setContainer( $container );
        ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );
    }
}
```

Depending of your needs, you can create a BaseController and extend it in your rest of controllers.

```
class UsersController extends Controller
```

In addition, you could add your keys in the parameters.yml file.

```
parameters:
    #your parameters...
    ParseAppId: your_id
    ParseRestKey: your_rest_key
    ParseMasterKey: your_master_key
```

> TIP: Note you can add have different Parse projects (dev and release
>   version). Add your parameters in your different parameters
>   configuration provides an easy way to handle this issue.

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    ....

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        parent::setContainer( $container );
        $app_id = $container->getParameter('ParseAppId');
        $rest_key = $container->getParameter('ParseRestKey');
        $master_key = $container->getParameter('ParseMasterKey');
        ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );
    }
}
```